# jquery outerwidth submenu items

Tags: jquery, count, width, html-lists

i'm looking for a way to calculate the total width of de level 2 items and put it in the ul.
I have looked at some jquery thinks like outerWidth and .lengt but can't figure it out.

thanks in advance

```
    $('#menu li:has(ul)  ul').each(function()

<ul>
 <li>level 1</li>
 <li>
  <ul style="widht:??;">
   <li>level 2</li>
   <li>level 2</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>level 1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **[`width()`](https://api.jquery.com/width/)** method of jQuery will give you the calculated width of an element:

```
$(function(){
  $('#menu li:has("ul")').each(function(){
    alert($(this).width());
  });
});
```

> Get the current computed width for the
>   first element in the set of matched
>   elements.

http://api.jquery.com/width/

[image]
<sub>(source: [jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/images/0042_04_04.png))</sub>